# Vertically centered text in p5.js is not aligned properly

Tags: javascript, fonts, vertical-alignment, p5.js, text-alignment

I recently started using p5.js more and noticed that when I the textAlign() function to center text, it is offset higher than the coordinates I specify when calling text(). The amount it is offset seems to be constant between different font sizes, being approximately fontSize()/12 above the y-coordinate I entered.

An example of this can be seen at [this p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/TetroGem/sketches/0_XrsEWGo), showing the default centering on the left, and the text being offset by fontSize()/12 on the right, having it be properly centered at varying text sizes.

Is there a way I could fix this issue and have all text be aligned properly without having to specify in each call of text that I want the text to be shifted down the amount of pixels needed for it to be properly centered? Is there a way I can modify the text function to have this functionality built in?

(Edit: I was able to "solve" this issue by overwriting the default text function with my own code, though I don't know if this is very good practice. A link to the fix can be found [here](https://editor.p5js.org/TetroGem/sketches/92tBU2H4X), with the fixed text alignment in black and the default p5.js alignment in green.)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with what you think of as the vertical "center" of the glyphs. From you example it is evident that you think of the "center" as the center line of the capital letters. However, by this metric all lower case letters would appear mostly below center and it also fails to take into account glyph descent (that is, the amount of certain lower case glyphs that appear below the font baseline).

Here is an example that I think clearly demonstrates how the various vertical positioning types work.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  noLoop();
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  redraw();
}

function draw() {
  let w = width / 4;
  
  push();
  stroke('blue');
  line(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);
  pop();
  
  drawText(0, 0, w, height, TOP);
  drawText(w, 0, w, height, CENTER);
  drawText(w * 2, 0, w, height, BASELINE);
  drawText(w * 3, 0, w, height, BOTTOM);
}

const str = 'Age';
const size = 48;

function drawText(x, y, w, h, valign) {
  push();
  textSize(size);
  textAlign(LEFT, valign);
  let tw = textWidth(str);
  let yOff = 0;
  switch (valign) {
    case TOP:
      yOff = -size / 2;
      break;
    case BOTTOM:
      yOff = size / 2;
      break;
    case BASELINE:
      yOff = size / 2 - textDescent();
  }
  
  stroke('limegreen');
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noFill();
  rect(x + w / 2, y + h / 2, tw, size);
  
  translate(x + w / 2 - tw / 2, height / 2 + yOff);
  
  stroke('red');
  line(0, 0, tw, 0);
  
  strokeWeight(4);
  point(0, 0);
  
  noStroke();
  fill('black');
  text(str, 0, 0);
  pop();
}
```

```css
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```